# Is there a way to set a JFileChooser to start from a certain file?

Tags: java

I've created a file chooser as such:

```
private JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(".");
```

Now this obviously opens up the current folder, in eclipse its the workshop folder. How do I make it so that it starts from where I have a certain file. I tried:

```
private JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser("pictureFile.png");
```

but it doesn't go to the file with that name.

EDIT:

Is there a way to add a picture file to my package folder for the project in eclipse?

Comment: Do you mean that the file chooser should search a directory for you? I'm afraid that you'll have to program that yourself. A file name alone isn't a good way to locate a directory.

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t use [setSelectedFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile-java.io.File-)?

Comment: I have found out the file path. 

     File fil = new File("picture.png");
   String filPath = fil.getAbsolutePath();

I cant do jfc.setDirectory(filpath) and if I set it to fil nothing happens. Nvm it didnt actually get the filepath.. Back to square one.

Answer (score 2):

There's a constructor for that
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser(java.io.File)